# InnoDB index shows 'zero' size for a table with a primary key

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table with a primary key, which is as below :

```
show create table com_zone;
 +----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                               |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| com_zone | CREATE TABLE `com_zone` (
 `domain` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and it has a plenty of data(around 1 million rows), however, when I check the index size it shows zero :

```
SELECT index_length/POWER(1024,1) NDXSIZE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema='zone_import' AND table_name='com_zone';
+---------+
| NDXSIZE |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
```

So, why does it show '0' index size when it has a PK index ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL + InnoDB table size question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914492/mysql-innodb-table-size-question)

Comment: @Alma: Nope this is different.

Answer (score 1):

"0" is correct.  In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered with the data.  So, there is no extra space consumed by that index.  Any *secondary* index would be tallied in `index_length`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a compressed table?  Mine is currently showing an index of size 0 as well - perhaps because since the numbers are already in the data, they compress fully?  Doesn't completely make sense.

Also try the query w/o the "POWER(1024,1)", just to see if there's some issue with it rounding the division to an integer when it's less than one or something...